# ip адрес. база моб.операторов

Tags: ip, php

Добрый день уважаемые участники. Помогите разобраться со следующим вопросом.
В общем потребовалась мне как-то база мобильных операторов. Сам я в этом новичек, и в ip ниче не понимаю=( к сожалению это так. Но, учусь быстро и рассчитываю на вашу помошь.

Скачал я одну базу, где все значения представлены в xml файле вида:

```
<operator id="11" name="TELE2" label="tele2" tld="RU" country="Россия" publish="1" mnc="250-20">
  <range ip1="1306001408" ip2="1306132479" mode="0" global="0" /> 
  <range ip1="1404225536" ip2="1404227071" mode="0" global="0" /> 
  <range ip1="1404256256" ip2="1404272639" mode="0" global="0" /> 
  <range ip1="1404272640" ip2="1404305407" mode="0" global="0" /> 
  </operator>
```

Как я понял, ip1 и ip2 это диапазон ip адресов... Как видите адреса представлены в числовом виде (если это так).

Так вот у меня возник вопрос.

1. Как преобразовать адрес из базы в привычный вид (192.168.0.1 - пример),или наоборот, адрес преобразовать к виду из базы. читал что сравнивать целочисленные адреса проще, и меньше времени это занимает.
2. Например определил я ip адрес через `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`, выполнил пункт 1. Но не понимаю как сравнить его с базой? Меня ставит в тупик этот диапазон. Вот вообще не соображу что с чем сравнивать что-бы не пролететь и все учесть....

Пока вроде все... Сильно не ругайтесь, это для меня ново и я только учусь. Буду признателен за подробную помощь нубу=)

UP.

Да, действительно ip закодирован в ip2long. Попробовал некоторые пробить, получилось, оператор совпал. Большое спасибо!

Понял, буду сравнивать так...

```
mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `operator` WHERE `min` <= '$iplong' AND `max` >= '$iplong'"
```

Comment: @Александр Маслов, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

какой нафиг explode()? Зачем велосипед делать, уже давно все написано!

```
ip2long('127.0.0.1'); // получим числовое значение

long2ip(2130706433); // получим IP из числа
```